# Show notes with headline in App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, administration

There seems to be an issue when viewing notes on mobile.

**To reproduce: -> mobile app -> contact -> view notes**

It only displays the content of the notes and the author and the date, but not the subject line. This sometimes causes confusion when the subject line contains context for the note (like whether the note is a personal thought, a log of a call etc).

**I'd basically like to view the notes like that:**

AUTHOR / DATE

HEADLINE

TEXT

I did some searching and went through relevant setup options, but couldn't find something. Is that even customizable?

[image]